# Kentico Kontent DeliveryClient.Build in Kentico Portal could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, kentico, kentico-kontent

I am attempting to call Kentico Kontent using their `DeliveryClient` in a Kentico Portal project that doesn't have dependency injection.  This project would like to migrate to Kontent but would like a new feature in the extisting project to be implemented with Kontent before the transition.

After installing the Kontent Delivery SDK, here's my code

```
var clientTest = DeliveryClientBuilder.WithProjectId("MyProjectId").Build();
```

I get a runtime error

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Obviously, this project doesn't have dependency injection and I hear setting it up in a portal project is difficult if not impossible.  So I decide to new up my own delivery client as outlined in Kentico's [blog post](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/building-an-mvc-site-with-kentico-cloud-part-1)

```
var test = new DeliveryClient(options);
```

But `DeliveryClient` is marked internal: `'DeliveryClient' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

How do I proceed?

Details

- Kentico.Kontent.Delivery 12.3.0
- Kentico version 12.0.22
- .Net Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue was much dumber.  I had installed the Kontent Delivery Client nuget sdk in another project and only referenced it in this one.  Installing it for this project solved the problem.  I am able to call the builder without any errors now.

Answer (score 0):

Although the `Kentico.Kontent.Delivery 12.*` targets `netstandard2.0` which means it [should be compatible with .NET Framework 4.6.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), there is [evidence](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-net/issues/185) that this setup can cause issues. There are a few things that I would recommend before trying anything else:

1. Upgrade to .NET 4.8 (or at least to 4.7.2)
2. Enable [Automatic Binding Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection) in your project by adding:

```html
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

No matter how you instantiate/register the DeliveryClient (`DeliveryClientBuilder` [`services.AddDeliveryClient()`](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-boilerplate-net/blob/master/src/content/Kentico.Kontent.Boilerplate/Startup.cs#L37)), the SDK always uses `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` internally, so there is no workaround. You will need to address the assembly binding problem.